# How to configure proxifer on pc which uses a proxy server or http filter to access the Internet

Tags: networking, proxy

In my college I used proxifier program to access blocked sites. I had to add a proxy setting in my "proxy servers" like

```
 Address=myipaddress as what my ip address on whatismyip.com
 port   =3128
```

and everything worked fine.

Now in my office I use the internet through a network proxy or Http filter(Microsoft TMG). my proxy server address is suppose "**proxy_address**" with port 8080.

When I use do the same thing as I did in college doesn't work.

How to configure proxifier on my pc which uses a proxy already to access the Internet.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your IT department? There might be a good reason why it doesn't work, and why certain sites are blocked.

Comment: It's not IT department which blocked the sites. It's my office's policy to block social sites like fb, twitter.